# On StanfordCoreNLP usage on sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

This a question on StanfordCoreNLP usage on sentiment analysis. I am not sure, based on my exploration  "SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class" has been changed to "SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class". Because I get "SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree cannot be resolved to a type". However when i changed to "SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class" I get NULL.   Can someone please clarify? Thank you!
I am using below code available in internet. I found most implementations are similar. I encounter same problem in almost all implementations i tried.

```
package crawler;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.*;


public class NLP {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findSentiment("life is good.");
    }

    public static void findSentiment(String line) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        int mainSentiment = 0;

        if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("line:"+line);
            int longest = 0;
            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(line);
            for (CoreMap sentence : annotation
                    .get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                Tree tree = sentence
                        .get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
                int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
                String partText = sentence.toString();
                if (partText.length() > longest) {
                    mainSentiment = sentiment;
                    longest = partText.length();
                }

            }
        }
        if (mainSentiment == 2 || mainSentiment > 4 || mainSentiment < 0) {
            System.out.println("Neutral " + line);
        }
        else{
        }
        /*
         * TweetWithSentiment tweetWithSentiment = new TweetWithSentiment(line,
         * toCss(mainSentiment)); return tweetWithSentiment;
         */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 from here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/
2. Some sample code to access sentiment:

   ```
   import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.Mention;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.*;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

   import java.util.Properties;

   public class SentimentExample {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           Annotation document = new Annotation("The movie was great!");
           Properties props = new Properties();
           props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
           StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
           pipeline.annotate(document);
           for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
               System.out.println("---");
               System.out.println(sentence);
               System.out.println(sentence.get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class));
               System.out.println(sentence.get(SentimentClass.class));

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I worked with 3.5 (3.6 could not be found in maven repository.   Thank you! One quick question. Score value is NaN from tree.score() of                                                    Tree tree=sentence.get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class); How to get right score value? Thanks!